# Requirements to move farm servers

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, server-farm, vmware

We have SharePoint 2016 on VM and we need to move to different Call center and move all VM's also to another VM .
Any specific requirements need to consider before moving the SharePoint Farm?

Comment: Will the move include a change of the Active Directory Domain?

Comment: No the Active directory will be the same, but we may change the servers name

Answer (score 0):

Without more info, there are no special actions you need to take other than shut down all SharePoint + SQL VMs that are part of the farm and move the VMs to the new virtualization host.

If you're changing subnets as part of the move, then you'll need to change the IPs of all of the VMs appropriately and fix up any DNS records as required.